# Logic behind If completed condition with not statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am following a memory-game tutorial and the next piece of code was used so we can know which cards were flipped. Now i am trying to grasp my little head around this piece of code and i know its super simple, but i can't seem to understand it.

```
var allTheCards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

allTheCards.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', flipTheCard));

    var flipCard = false;
    var firstCard, secondCard;

    function flipTheCard() {
        this.classList.add('flip');
        debugger;
            if (!flipCard) {
                flipCard = true;
                firstCard = this;

            } 
            else {
                flipCard = false;
                secondCard = this;
                console.log(flipCard);

            };
    };
```

First we declare flipCard as false and later in the if statement the condition is (!flipCard) which is basically true. I followed the debugger and after the first conditions it returns the flipCard as true, but how is that condition fulfilled really? (does the click on the element do it... or what)

If anyone can tell me this in plain English, it would be really helpfull, i did lose most of my day yesterday banging my head at this.

Comment: I'm not following your question... if `flipCard` is `false`, the condition will be met and `flipCard = true` will change it to `true`. Is that the point you're not understanding?

Comment: The DOM and its elements emit specific events when interacted with (clicks, scrolling). You register functions associated with DOM element(s) and an event in the browser's process using the addEventListener function. When an event is emitted from an element, it triggers every registered function associated with that element's event. You've assigned a reference to your `flipTheCard` function to three DOM elements' events. When any of those elements are clicked, `flipTheCard`is triggered through the function reference passed as the second argument in addEventListener.

Comment: so how does the (!flipCard) part makes the first condition true? By just clicking on the element and doing nothing more?
What is confusing here is that we set the flipCard as false and the condition is (!flipCard => meaning oposite => meaning true?). So how is this condition fulfilled so that the value is set to true in the next line.